# Audio5js player not working for Chrome on Mac

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

Audio5js is a html5 with flash compaitibility for older browsers. Here is the link for the source code and the developer website

Github: https://github.com/zohararad/audio5js

I have used angular example of the player

I have create a plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/Ma1zzsze1R31p3QZOyW8?p=preview

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/zohararad/audio5js/master/audio5.js"></script>
<!--include ngAudio5.js after audio5.js-->
<script src="ngAudio5.js"></script>

<script>
  //inject Audio5 service into our app
  var app = angular.module('myapp',['Audio5']);

  //Inject the AudioService singleton
  var PlayCtrl = function ($scope, AudioService) {
    //bind AudioService to scope
    $scope.player = AudioService;
    //Load the song, every event, class method and Instance attribute from audio5js are accessible from the template
    $scope.player.load('http://danosongs.com/music/danosongs.com-orb-of-envisage.mp3');

    //example of event binding
    $scope.player.on('timeupdate',function(){
      $scope.$apply();
    })
  }
</script>
```

The weird thing is it is working on all the browsers except for chrome on mac.

The version of chrome: Version 36.0.1985.125
version of MAC OS: OS X 10.9.4

Please see the plunk and let me know if there is any issue

Comment: I cant find what's wrong.  But one thing that is definitely strange is how it configures the audio player to Flash (when on chrome on mac)...when it should be just html5.

Comment: Here is the demo http://zohararad.github.io/audio5js/ from the author, this demo is working on chrome on mac, but when I try the same, this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove codecs=mp3, when audio type is mp3 in js file. It is fixed by the developer. The Sourcecode on github is updated